# Javascript not working in FireFox for Android, for my site only

Tags: javascript, android, ruby-on-rails-3, firefox, heroku

(Apologies for the tag soup - I'm really not sure what's causing my problem!)

I have a Ruby-on-Rails site served from heroku.com. When visiting the site on a variety of desktop browsers, the javascript I serve works flawlessly; when visiting the site from my phone running FireFox for Android, the javascript does not work at all - modernizr is not firing (I can tell because of elements visible only if modernizr adds the `js` class), confirm dialogs don't appear, and forms are submitted by normal POST instead of AJAX.

I have javascript turned on in FF for Android, and can verify that it works; for instance, StackOverflow's questions are correctly highlighted or dimmed according to my interested tags. I can see (just about...) from heroku's logs that my phone is requesting the app's combined javascript file.

What steps can I take to work out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would get Google Chrome for Android and see if it is has the same problem. This tell you if it is a browser issue or a a javascript issue in your web page.
You also may want to check out this link: https://quality.mozilla.org/docs/mobile-firefox/firefox-mobile-enabling-the-error-console/

Comment: An initial look at Chrome suggests it's handling the JS - I'm seeing the js-only elements. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.

Comment: I hope the link helps resolve your issue and thank for voting up my answer.